# Video in AVPlayer not changing size at same rate as player itself

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I'm having an odd problem with animating an `AVPlayer`. I'm changing the size of a `UIView` using Layout Constraints and animating the change with a `layoutIfNeeded()` in an animation block. Every subview in the animated `UIView` animates properly, including the `AVPlayer` itself, but the video inside the player does not animate with the same animation curve.

The `AVPlayer` is embedded in a container view through an `AVPlayerController`. The container is a subview of the view being animated.

A video of the animation shows the problem pretty clearly: http://goo.gl/DGq8rO

I know the `AVPlayer` is changing size on the correct animation curve because you can see the top of the player control bar animating at the correct rate, so this has to be some issue with the video itself. I'm not too well versed in they player side of `AVKit`/`AVFoundation`, so any guidance would be appreciated.

This is the function that the animation is called from:

```
func updateSize(duration: NSTimeInterval, _ dampening: CGFloat) {
    heightConstraint.constant = actualHeight
    if duration > 0 {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: dampening, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: nil, animations: {
            self.superview!.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

I've tested it with using the basic `animateWithDuration` function (the one without `usingSpringWithDampening`), and it works properly. This is more of a workaround than a fix, though. I'm really looking for some way to use `usingSpringWithDempening` animations, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce it when I animate size and position of containerView's superview simultaneously. If the containerView is a normal view instead of a AVPlayer view, everything works fine.

My suggestion is to use `animateWithDuration:animations:` instead of using `usingSpringWithDamping`. I think there is a `CASpringAnimation` used behind it, causing one of the sublayers's height to always animate from the original value to new value with a different duration. You can also animate its size firstly with a normal animation and then its position with spring animation.

Comment: This does work - the video animates at the same rate as the player - but this feels more like a workaround than a fix. I really want to be able to use Spring Animations from the size of the player, though, and this doesn't accomplish that. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I'd recommend you use [RBBAnimation](https://github.com/robb/RBBAnimation) or some other 3rd party library, the final result looks like a spring animation, you can see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/11ulivvf1ok9bz5/MyMovie12.mp4?dl=0).

Comment: The animation in that video still has the same problem - the video inside the player scales at a different rate than the player. You can see it pretty clearly when the Reset button is pressed.

Comment: That's because I didn't animate when resetting, anyway, here is another [close result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xd37f3ub7fjsvbr/CloseResult.mp4?dl=0) to what you are looking for, it uses a UIView springAnimation to scale and center and another UIView animation to change size constraints and original Y constraint.